# PHP Pear HTML-IT doesn't render after migrating from PHP5 to PHP7

Tags: php, templates, pear, html-templates

I recently moved one ancient PHP app originally from year 2004 to a freshly installed Linux host. Originally it was written in PHP4 but it worked without any modifications on PHP5.

Now there is problem with rendering Pear HTML_Template_IT with PHP7 and Phar. Non-working code looks like this

```
<?php
require_once("HTML/Template/IT.php");

class Layout_normal
{


    function __construct($views)
    {
        $this->views = $views;
        $Tt = new HTML_Template_IT("../tpl");
        $Tt->loadTemplatefile("layoutNormal.tpl");
        foreach($views as $view => $data)
        {
            if($view == "main") {
                $Tt->setVariable("PAGE", $data);
            }
            elseif($view == "help")
            {
                $Tt->setCurrentBlock("help");
                $Tt->setVariable("HELP", $data);
                $Tt->parseCurrentBlock();
            }
            elseif($view == "pagename") $Tt->setVariable("PAGENAME", $data);
            elseif($view == "active") $active = $data;
            elseif($view == "module") $module = $data;
       }
       $Tt->setVariable("MENU", $this->getMenu($view));
       $Tt->setVariable("TOPMENU", $this->getMenu($view));

       $this->page = $Tt->get();
   }

   // some more methods here

}
?>
```

From that code variable {{PAGE}} was rendered as expected, but {{MENU}} and {{TOPMENU}} does not render. This same code works in old PHP5 environment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that when current block was set to "help" `$Tt->setCurrentBlock("help");` it was never returned from there. So adding last line in here fixed the problem:

```
            elseif($view == "help")
            {
                $Tt->setCurrentBlock("help");
                $Tt->setVariable("HELP", $data);
                $Tt->parseCurrentBlock();
                $Tt->setCurrentBlock("__global__"); // <- THIS DID THE MAGIC
            }
```

In PHP5 you didn't need to set `__global__` back to current block, but after updating to PHP7 and newer version of Pear (Phar, API version 1.1.1 to be exact) you need to do that.